# Web Api: get child entities

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am new to Web Apis (I have an ASP.NET Core Web application with some Apis)

Suppose we have `Company`/`Employee` and we want to get all employees for a `Company` via an API.

I have Company controller and I would like to return Employees.

Suppose we want to get the employees via something like `/company/{id}/employees`

Is it correct like the following controller is formed :

```
public class CompanyController {

    [Route("/company/{id}/employees")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Employees(int id) {

        var company = await _repository.GetByIdAsync<Company>(id);
        return Ok(company.Employees);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose we want to get the employees via something like
> /company/{id}/employees
>
> Is it correct like the following controller is formed :
>
> ```
> public class CompanyController {
>
>     [Route("/company/{id}/employees")]
>     public async Task<IActionResult> Employees(int id) {
>
>         var company = await _repository.GetByIdAsync<Company>(id);
>         return Ok(company.Employees);
>     }
> }
> ```

Yes, you can use the above route, then, the request URL should like this: `https://localhost:44312/company/12/employees`

[**Note**] The Request URL doesn't contain the `api`.

Besides, if you want to add the `api` in the request url, you can also use the route configure:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CompanyController : ControllerBase
{ 
    // GET api/<CompanyController>/5/employees
    [HttpGet("{id}/employees")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        //query database and get the company and related employees. Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/
        return "Entered companyid value: "+ id;
    }
```

Then, the request URL like this: `https://localhost:44312/api/company/12/employees`.

You could check the following screenshot:

[image]

More detail information about routing in asp.net core, you can refer the following links:

[Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ar)

Answer (score 0):

this question about linq eagger loading

[enter link description here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/eager-loading-in-entity-framework.aspx)

```
  using System;
using System.Data.Entity; 
   
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
        {
            var stud1 = ctx.Students.Include(s => s.Standard)
                            .Where(s => s.StudentName == "Bill")
                            .FirstOrDefault<Student>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the OP si not about how to filter entities, but how to oraganise and route controllers